# What is the best way to implement multithreaded SSH logins using Netmiko with Python?

Tags: multithreading, ssh, python-multithreading, paramiko, netmiko

I have a list of network devices I need to SSH into in order to get the output of a command. I'm using Netmiko (Python). The SSH login credentials of each "login request" are JSON objects sent as an array through a single POST request to my Python server:

```
[{ IP: ..., 
  CMD: ... },
 { IP: ..., 
  CMD: ... }, 
 ...,
 { IP: ..., 
  CMD: ... }]
```

So far, my thought process for this has been:

1. Group the requests by host IP (many of them belong to the same host)
2. Process each request from the same host in a multithreaded fashion.
3. Group together the outputs from each request and return.

And this is what I've implemented:

```python
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Body
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from pydantic import BaseModel
import logging
import json
from typing import Any
import uvicorn
import concurrent.futures  
 
format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=format, filename='CNM.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.INFO)
 
app = FastAPI()
 
def handle_request(payload):
    try:
        device = {
            'device_type': payload['dev_vendor'],
            'host': payload['IP'],
            'username': 'user',
            'password': 'password'
        }
 
        conn = ConnectHandler(**device)
        conn.read_timeout_override = 20
       
        output = conn.send_command(payload['CMD'])
 
        conn.disconnect()
       
        return output
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
 
@app.post("/ssh_login/")
def ssh_login(reqs: Any = Body(None)):
    hosts_list = []
 
    for req in reqs:
        hosts_list.append(req['IP'])
 
    hosts_set = set(hosts_list)
 
    responses = []
 
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for host in hosts_set:
            host_reqs = []
 
            # Get the host's requests
            for req in reqs:
                if req['IP'] == host:
                    host_reqs.append(req)
                   
            for output in executor.map(handle_request, host_reqs):
                responses.append(output)
 
    return responses
```

Although faster than a conventional synchronous approach, it turns out to be slow IMO, ~1s per request.

I thought that opening a single SSH connection for a host and running all commands in parallel with the executor could solve the problem, but I researched and it seems not viable (looks like sharing the same SSH connection across threads would be problematic).

Is there a way to optimize this and gain performance?

Comment: “Process each request from the same host in a multithreaded fashion.”: doesn’t make sense. Process each request from *different* hosts in a multithreaded fashion, but unless you have multiple connections to the same host you can’t multithread. A connection is not multithreaded.